# How can I make a vertical v-btn with Vuetify?

Tags: css, vue.js, button, frontend, vuetify.js

I am trying to keep the icon as it is (horizontal) and the button name vertical in the upward direction. But somehow the suggestions to similar questions I found don't seem to work on my button. Does anyone have an idea?

```
    <v-btn fixed right tile style="z-index: 5">
          <v-icon left>mdi-icon-name</v-icon>
          ButtonName
    </v-btn>
```

Comment: can you share an image of what you're trying to accomplish so there isn't any misunderstanding?

Comment: something like this https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/VwLyErJ?editable=true&editors=101

Comment: Thanks, @BoussadjraBrahim! I got the result I wanted by using ```style="transform:rotate(-90deg)"``` for v-btn and ```style="transform:rotate(90deg)"``` for v-icon following your suggestion.

Comment: sounds like an css issue to me. not really related to vue or vuetify directly

Answer (score 1):

apply CSS on v-icon only, keeping button horizontal:

```
<v-icon style="transform:rotate(90deg)" ...
```